# How can I ever know what workspace I have open?

Tags: codeblocks

I have CodeBlocks configured to open a blank workspace when I open it.

I open Codeblocks.

I right click the blank workspace, select `Rename workspace` and rename the workspace to `TestWorkspace1`.

I right click the workspace and click `Save workspace as`, Codeblocks unhelpfully shows a file save dialog that is preconfigured to save the workspace with the name `default.workspace`, even though I just renamed it.

In the File save dialog I once again rename the workspace to `TestWorkspace1` and save it.

I close Codeblocks.

In File explorer I click on the `TestWorkspace1.workspace` that I just saved. CodeBlocks opens it and displays it as `Workspace` in the Project tree.

Every workspace I create, rename and open, CodeBlocks just displays as `Workspace` in the Project tree.

So if I have several workspaces open in separate CodeBlocks instances, how am I supposed to tell which is which?

More generally how can I tell which workspace I have open?